# Use Gradle task functionality in another task

Tags: gradle

I have a Gradle Tar task that creates an archive file with my project sources.

Now I need to duplicate this functionality but to add a file into the archive.

Is there a way to extend/inherit the original task functionality without duplicating the code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use the [with](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Tar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Tar:with(org.gradle.api.file.CopySpec%5B%5D)) method. The API may look a bit weird as it says it takes a `CopySpec` as input, but a `Tar` task is actually also a `CopySpec`.

Example (Groovy DSL):

```java
task myDefaultTar(type: Tar) {
    archiveBaseName = "default"
    from("$buildDir/default.txt")
}

task myOtherTar(type: Tar) {
    archiveBaseName = "other"
    with(myDefaultTar)
    from("$buildDir/additional_file.txt")
}
```